# F. Current Dependent Current Source

Tags: ltspice

I am a beginner in simulation on LTspice. I have this circuit to simulate but each time it displays an 'unknown controling source 100' error. I don't know how I should add it and or.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Can you simplify your model and see where the problem is? Where did you get the U1 model from? Does it work on its own?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to simulate? You're using a bunch of H-sources (current dependent voltage source), when it looks like you want V-sources (independent voltage source)....but then it looks like you're trying to do an AC analysis so we need more info before we can help you.

Comment: yes I think I was wrong, I changed my diet.
i want to try to simulate the apex microtechnology pa107. my goal is to put a very low input voltage and try to see if the PA107 can amplify it (high voltage).

Comment: j'ai reussi a faire la simulation, mais la sortie de l'amplificateur est 0V je ne sais pas pourquoi, je n'arrive pas a comprendre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you further clarified in the comments about what you are trying to do, there are a couple things wrong here.  First, you're using a bunch of H-sources (current dependent voltage sources), when it looks like you want V-sources (independent voltage sources).  These are simply called "voltage" in the main component library.  Your 4 rail voltages should be fine setting these to a DC voltage level via a simple right-click on the symbol after you place it.

[image]

---

Second, you're trying to do an AC small signal analysis (`.ac`) when what you really want is a transient analysis (`.tran`).  You also need to make this input voltage source a SINE or PULSE waveform.  This is found by right-clicking on the symbol and clicking "Advanced" to bring up the function select menu.

[image]

---

I believe I correctly acquired the model you are trying to use from here:
https://www.apexanalog.com/resources/spicemodels/poa/apexpoweropamps.zip

I auto-generated a symbol similar to yours and here is a screenshot of the correct version of what I think you want to accomplish with your simulation:

[image]

Comment: Merci beaucoup, voua avez fait beaucoup d'effort, je vous remercie énormément. j'essayerai  de refaire mon shema comme ce que  vous avez mis en photo et j’espère que sa va marcher.

Comment: @ChàiMà Please use English only, this site means to be international and not everyone may know French. Also, if you think this answer solves your problem, mark it down (the check mark to the left) so that others, in the future, searching for similar problems, will see this question with an accepted answer. Welcome to ee.se.

Comment: my simulation does not work :( the error message is "" unckoun spice device type in -vaux vs ""

Comment: @ChàiMà Then you are still doing something wrong.  Please try again.  I considered pasting my `.asc` file text, but decided that it's more important that you figure out what you're doing wrong so you can learn from it and apply it going forward...especially in such a trivial example.

Comment: I also want to mention that LTspice will throw up the error log (after simulation is done) because the model from Apex tries to use lambda with a Level 3 MOSFET.  For now, you can just ignore and close the error log window since the model will still function.  Tweaking subcircuit files from manufacturers is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: YES I know thank you. Its been 3 days since I tried with this circuit but it doesn't work. the same error is displayed Unknown SPICE device type "-" in "-vaux vs" the problem is "-". I tried to remove the sign - it shows me another error 'Multiple instances of' Vaux '

Comment: on the other hand to put the name of the different connections like (+ vaux, -vaux, vs ...) I made "" edit ==> Spice directice "" "and I write the name of the pin and it is when I do like this that my simulation does not work. On the other hand when I do "" "edit => text" "" "my simulation works but the name of the pins on the shema are in blue it's not like yours in black. and normally I will have an output voltage amplified and inverted because it is an inverting amplifiers on the other hand the output is just amplified, it is not inverted

Comment: @ChàiMà, you need to label nets using the F4 key.  See Help section titled "Label a Node Name", or translated version here:
https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=en&tl=fr&u=http%3A%2F%2Fltwiki.org%2FLTspiceHelpXVII%2FLTspiceHelp%2Fhtml%2FLabel_a_node_name.htm

Comment: thank you very much I corrected and I had the same results as you

Comment: the simulation works but I still have errors (unrecognized parameter "lambda" -- ignored )

Comment: @ChàiMà I already explained this error in a previous comment.  Please read above.

Comment: Yes I have read. I am starting work on a project 'creation of an electronic card'. these errors will not be able to damage the operation of the card. once i will do the routing ect? in the presence of these errors

Comment: @ChàiMà, There is no way any model can predict real-world results to 100% accuracy.  Also, SPICE won't tell you when things violate voltage/current/wattage specifications.  There is no animation of explosion/smoking to tell you when something will blow up in real life.  You need to be aware of this when analyzing the simulation results.  Anyway, if the log errors bother you, edit the `.LIB` file and change the `LEVEL=3` instances to `LEVEL=1`.  The errors will go away and the results won't change.

Comment: Thank you very much i'm really grateful

Comment: @ChàiMà, if you accept the answer it will help future people with your same initial question about Current Dependent Current Sources.